# In Spark, is it better to have many small workers or few bigger workers

Tags: apache-spark, distributed-computing

A Spark cluster consists of a driver that distributes tasks to multiple worker nodes. Each worker can take up a number of tasks equal to the amount of cores available. So I'd think that the speed at which a task finishes depends on the total available cores.

Consider the following cluster configurations, using AWS EC2 as an example:

- 2 [m5.4xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) (16 vCPU/cores, 64GB RAM) workers for a total of 32 cores / 128GB RAM

OR

- 8 [m5.xlarge](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) (4 vCPU/cores, 16GB RAM) workers for a total of 32 cores / 128GB RAM

I'm using those instances as an example; it's not about those instances specifically but about the general idea that you can have the same total amount of cores + RAM with different configurations. Would there be any difference between the performance of those two cluster configurations? Both would have the same total amount of cores and RAM, and same ratio of RAM/core. For what kind of job would you choose one and for what the other? Some thoughts I have on this myself:

- The configuration with 8 smaller instances might have a higher total network bandwidth since each workers has it's own connection
- The configuration with 2 bigger instances might be more efficient when shuffling, since more cores can share the memory on a worker instead of having to shuffle across the network, so lower network overhead
- The configuration with 8 smaller instances has better resiliency, since if one worker fails it's only one out of eight failing rather than one out of two.

Do you agree with the statements above? What other considerations would you make when choosing between different configurations with equal amount of total RAM / cores?

Comment: having more than 1 worker node already gave you resiliency. So i will not count it. The biggest impact is see is the drop in network usage -- which will significantly improve the job performance. Btw, spark 3.3 recommends atleast 8cores - 16 cores per node. If you have auto scaling then in idle time you are not paying price for the fat nodes -- But i would still prefer fat nodes as they get the work done quickly. I will rather compensate it by going to EC2 reserved instances